# Chrome Extension и Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension, google-analytics

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно отследить количество установок хром расширения через гугл аналитику в background скрипте, при этом не открывая никаких лендингов ?

Comment: Через Ajax xhr fetch

Comment: Информация о просмотрах и установках доступна в панеде управления расширениями.